# How should I construct this json return from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have some data, organised by date, as a [datetime index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html). I then subset it so it is effectively irregular:

```
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/8/2018', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['data'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date', drop=True)
df = df[df['data'] > 75]
```

In my *service* (this is not for interactive use) I am given a string which I pass to [`pandas.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to aggregate my time data to any level. The string is supplied directly to the `rule` argument, and can be values like `'H'`, `'3T'`, `'Q'`, `'M'`

I would like to use the same string to create an json which is similar to the following structure:

```
{'my_aggregate_level_1': {'2018-01-01 03:00:00', '2018-01-01 07:00:00'},
'my_aggregate_level_2':{'2018-01-08 03:00:00'}}
```

The array will be 'ragged' i.e. not all records will be present, and not all keys in the json will have the same length of array.

The goals for a good solution are:

1. `my_aggregate_level` is the level set by the same string parameter as given to `resample`
2. the array in the aggregate level will always be the raw, datetime hourly values
3. *Ideally* the string parameter is not associated with a bunch of 'translatation rules' such as "If `'D'` then use `.strftime` like this, but if `'H'` use this and if `'M'` use this
4. `'H'` would just return a single array, of the raw values

So in practice if a `'D'` is supplied:

```
{'2018-01-01': {'2018-01-01 03:00:00', '2018-01-01 07:00:00'},
'2018-01-08':{'2018-01-08 03:00:00'}}
```

Note that there are two keys at daily level, with the values in the array split to the correct day.

If `'M'` is supplied:

```
{'2018-01': {'2018-01-01 03:00:00', '2018-01-01 07:00:00', '2018-01-08 03:00:00'}}
```

Note that this means the contents of the value array will be 3 in this example, as the 3 datetimes are all in the same month

### Things I've tried/looked at that I haven't made work well:

- `Groupers`, they look like they aggregate only, based on some rules. I specifically need to return the actual records
- Parseing a new column based on the `rule` argument would technically work, but it seems wrong as I would have to start converting each `rule` to a `strftime` or similar. I have not yet found a function that accepts the same character string and does not also perform aggregations
- Is setting a multi-index a solution to this? It might be but I'm not certain how to populate it in regards to the point above about the `'D'`, `'M'`, etc.
- custom resampler:

```
def custom_resampler(array_like):
    return array_like

df.resample('W').apply(custom_resampler)
```

Which is not working.

I understand, it may be that this is not solvable with the rules above, but I am probably not good enough at `pandas` yet to realise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE:

The return structure is infact a series, and as such can be filtered for empty list index points using this method:

```
df.resample('D').apply(custom_resampler).apply(len) > 0
```

### ORIGINAL:

I believe I have worked out a solution.

Specifically, I was using custom resamplers wrong, and in fact they can do the json conversion itself. I need to process a little to get to the result I need, but for now this is the answer:

```
def custom_resampler(array_like):
    return array_like.to_json()

df.resample('D').apply(custom_resampler)
```

Very happy to be corrected/refined/improved on this.

Comment: After testing, this is only a partial content. It will return a full index of each day/month imputed with empty lists, which is not correct. `'my_aggregate_level_1'` should only occur when it contains values.